# Generate random phone numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with more than 100,000 unique user ids and these user ids are repeated throughout .I want to assign all unique user ids with a random phone number and this number should be repeated in their second occurrence as well in the user ids column .

I have tried randbetween but this would give multiple phone numbers to similar user ids as well .

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:D1,2,FALSE),RAND()*(9999999999-1000000000)+1000000000)
```

the output should be like:

```
user_id name     phone
2       sam      202345456
2       sam      202345456
3       kate     654321231
4       lillian  765987432
3       kate     654321231
```

Comment: Maybe explain the real purpose of your code.

Comment: I hazard a guess it is for a password...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula works for me:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:$C1,2,FALSE),RAND()*(9999999999-1000000000)+1000000000)
```

[image]

I only modified the range for VLOOKUP().